# Is there a way to sign in to a Telegram behind proxy using Telethon?

Tags: python, proxy, telegram, http-proxy, telethon

I've used proxies from https://proxy2.webshare.io/ and Telethon documentation:
https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/signing-in.html

But it seems nothing is working to hide my location when starting a session. I've heard people use Proxifier but I want to try it this way firstly. Any sort of help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.